# Getting median with counts

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset, let's call it d1, with the following information:

```
ID count
1   5
2   2 
3   6 
4   6
5   4
6   3
```

If I would want the median, it would be calculated with [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,...,6,6,6], since there is a count with the amount of times repeated. The results would then be 3.5 (since we got 3 and 4 and we do the average between them). I've been trying to use limit with a subquery but I cannot and therefore I do not know how to get the middle value or the average of the ones in the middle when its even.

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding with my question. Double values are counted. You would use ID = 1 five times and so forth (as the array presented in the first sentence states). Please let me know if I am not expressing myself correctly in order to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this to be a relatively simple method:

```
select avg(id)
from (select x.*, 
             sum(cnt) over (order by id) as running_cnt,
             sum(cnt) over () as total_cnt
      from x
     ) x
where running_cnt >= total_cnt / 2.0 and
      running_cnt - cnt <= total_cnt / 2.0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f0a4233e9e052601e1089b941e90b798) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I really like this since I do not need to create a window (too complex for me) and It does not use median func. Most people seem to love @Haleemur post (see below), I am too new to fully understand it. That is why I have selected this as correct answer.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz . . . I answered because I found that answer overly complicated.

Answer (score 5):

you can *expand* the dataset using `generate_series` from 1 to `count` for each row, and then apply the `percentile_cont` ordered set aggregate function. This will work on postgresql 9.4+

Self contained example:

```
WITH x(id, cnt) as (
values
(1, 5),
(2, 2), 
(3, 6),
(4, 6),
(5, 4),
(6, 3)
)
SELECT percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) med
FROM x, generate_series(1,cnt)

# outputs:
med
3.5
```

Another option would be to use window functions to identify the position of the element(s) that should be averaged to get the median

```
WITH x(id,"cnt") as (
values
(1,5),
(2,2), 
(3,6),
(4,6),
(5,4),
(6,3)
)
, windowed AS (
  SELECT id, SUM(cnt) OVER w a, SUM(cnt) OVER u b, SUM(cnt) OVER v / 2.0 c
  FROM x
  WINDOW u AS (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
         v AS (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
         w AS (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
)
SELECT AVG(id) med
FROM windowed
WHERE c BETWEEN b AND a
```

Comment: 2nd option is a piece of art and would work even for massive values of count.

Comment: Aye. I am not worthy to tie your shoelaces.

Comment: Isn't `v AS (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),` the same as `v as ()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it is, but I wanted to be explicit as this is a SO answer. One can also replace `(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` with `(ORDER BY id)`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, you're making me blush.

Comment: Is the median function available in postgresql? I cannot find it

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz, you know what, it is not, and I had implemented it as a UDF aggregate function, and I'm just used to typing `median` in my workflow. I'm removing the first answer, as it won't work for anyone else who hasn't implemented a `median` UDF on their database.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz, updated with alternate _similar_ syntax that is valid in postgrseql 9.4 & above.